# What is the best way to do range based cross join in Presto?

Tags: window-functions, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table `event_log` in Athena which has logs collected from an event processing system. There are various stages in the system and each stage processes these events in sequential order. `start_time` column indicates the time at which the event entered the system and `end_time` is the time at which it exited. The system processes millions of events per day. And, we have data for a year in the below table.

| event_id | event_type | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | TypeA | T1 | T4 |
| E2 | TypeB | T2 | T6 |
| M1 | TypeM | T2 | T6 |
| E3 | TypeA | T3 | T7 |
| E4 | TypeB | T4 | T7 |
| E5 | TypeA | T5 | T8 |
| M2 | TypeM | T5 | T8 |
| E6 | TypeB | T6 | T9 |
| E7 | TypeA | T7 | T10 |
| E8 | TypeB | T8 | T11 |
| M3 | TypeM | T8 | T11 |

There are special type of events `TypeM` (marker events). I have to calculate the processing latency of these special events from these logs. From the table above, this can be achieved by filtering events of that type and compute the latency as `end_time - start_time`. In addition to that, I want to augment the latency with an additional info - number of events that were actively being processed in various stages of the system when this event was being processed.

```sql
-- sample event_log table
CREATE TABLE event_log AS 
SELECT * FROM ( 
    VALUES 
        ('E1','TypeA', 1, 4),  
        ('E2','TypeB', 2, 6),  
        ('M1','TypeM', 2, 6),  
        ('E3','TypeA', 3, 7),  
        ('E4','TypeB', 4, 7),  
        ('E5','TypeA', 5, 8),  
        ('M2','TypeM', 5, 8),  
        ('E6','TypeB', 6, 9),  
        ('E7','TypeA', 7, 10),  
        ('E8','TypeB', 8, 11),  
        ('M3','TypeM', 8, 11)  
) AS t (event_id, event_type, start_time, end_time) 

-- filtered marker table
CREATE TABLE marker_table AS
SELECT * FROM event_log
    WHERE event_type = 'TypeM'

-- Join with the filtered marker table on markers start and end time
SELECT mark.*,count(processed_events_in_band.event_id) AS events_processed_count
    FROM event_log processed_events_in_band
    JOIN marker_table mark
        ON processed_events_in_band.end_time between mark.start_time AND mark.end_time
    WHERE processed_events_in_band.event_type != 'TypeM'
    GROUP BY  mark.event_id
```

**Expected result**

| event_id | event_type | start_time | end_time | events_processed_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M1 | TypeM | T2 | T6 | 2 E1, E2 |
| M2 | TypeM | T5 | T8 | 4 E2, E3, E4, E5 |
| M3 | TypeM | T8 | T11 | 4 E5, E6, E7, E8 |

There are partitions on `end_time` (daily). Have been using them to reduce the data scan. Single day data can be up to 10m. Query should scale to that. Query took around 17 mins for marker table having 18K rows and event logs having 10m rows. There are around 2K parquet files to scan for this 10m rows. Don't think there is S3 read latency causing an issue here.

How do I optimize this query? What is the best way to get this data efficiently?

Comment: Is the question about improving performance of your query, meaning, reducing the 17min runtime?

Comment: Yes, it is about improving the performance and doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance:

- be aware that `CREATE TABLE` will write the output of the query on disk [(doc)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html). Consider using a common table expression instead:

```
with marker_table as (SELECT * FROM event_log
    WHERE event_type = 'TypeM')
select ...
```

- try using a condition with an `=` sign in the join. Presto will do a hash join which is a lot more efficient. In your case I would attempt truncating down start and truncating up end times and write the `ON` condition using equality of truncated times (up or down)
- always place the largest table to the left of the join ([doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/))
- if you want to add the list of events being processed, and not just the count, you can use the `array_agg` function ([doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html)) combined with `array_distinct` to produce a list of unique entries and `array_join` to join it into a string.

Comment: I am using `CREATE TABLE` just for this demonstration. I am primarily interested in optimizing the join query only.

Comment: Its that `SELECT` query that takes about 17 mins. I am following best practices like larger table on the left, paritioning, etc. And, not keen on the actual events, the count should do. Even an approximation of count should be good enough.

Comment: Is there a way we can leverage `window functions` here? I am not sure what range to use here though.